# How to retrieve the value of the selector in AJAX and save it in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, selector

I have the prop() method and want to retrieve the "show_pdf1" in php and save the value there to process something before returning the end result of readPdf.php.
How do I do this without using another method, but with the property method?

`$('#show_pdf1').prop('src', 'php/readPdf.php');`

In php I want to save it as

`$value = 'show_pdf1'; //retrieve the selector here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post('php/readPdf.php', {whichFrame:whichFrame,value:value},
function(data) {
  $('#'+whichFrame+'').prop('src', data);
});
```

whichFrame and value are javascript methods where you take the value by id from different tags.

My readPdf.php return the file.

```
<?php
echo $file1; //this get set as data as a 'src' attribute.
?>
```

That's it, thanks anyway!